# Is it possible to install angular-ui-tinymce with the help of nuget package manager console?

Tags: tinymce, bower, bower-install

I came across a problem when installing angular-ui-tinymce with the help of nuget package manager console.
This is the message I get:

```
PM> $ bower install angular-ui-tinymce --save-dev
$ : The term '$' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ $ bower install angular-ui-tinymce --save-dev
+ ~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ($:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

All help is greatly appriciated

Greetings
Attila

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bower is a package manager itself - why would you want to use both Bower and Nuget to install the package?  Assuming you have Bower installed properly you can install `angular-ui-tinymce` with Bower:

```
bower install angular-ui-tinymce --save-dev
```

...not sure why you are prefacing the command with a `$` but its not proper syntax and that is what your error above is telling you.

The `PM>` prompt in your code suggests you are in the NuGet Package manager - no need to be in there if you want to use Bower to get the package.

Check out this article on Bower vs NuGet as it may help clarify your confusion...

http://simplyaprogrammer.com/2014/06/why-bower-is-better-than-nuget.html